# .htaccess file works at localhost or not ?? if yes How?

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, localhost

I have the following code in my htaccess file:

---

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews


RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]


------------------------------------------------
```

And my .htaccess directory like this :

```
..wamp/www/.htaccess
```

And my website directory like this

```
..wamp/www/Careers
```

When I load my careers folder or localhost it gives an error :

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Comment: What can you see in apache error log? It's probably in `wamp/logs/` folder. It should have an error. Maybe your rewrite module is not loaded?

Comment: take a look in your ERROR LOG (Apache) and locate the error.

Comment: How to load rewrite module ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a .htaccess on your site, it may be interfering with the web page you are trying to load into your browser. Please double check the .htaccess configuration. Any syntax errors will cause a 500 Internal Server Error message to be displayed instead of your website.

To confirm whether a misconfiguration .htaccess is the cause of the 500 Internal Server error, either remove or rename the .htaccess file temporarily and then try to reload the page.

You can check with online [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)